# Bootstrap form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jqbootstrapvalidation

I am trying to validate username and password field using bootstrap validator
I have included css and js for bootstrap validator. 
form id to validate is `#login`

Code is as below

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                       <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
            <script type='text/javascript' src="js/bootstrapvalidator-dist-0.4.5/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src="js/bootstrapvalidator-dist-0.4.5/dist/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#login').bootstrapValidator({
                        feedbackIcons: {
                            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                        },
                        fields: {
                            userName: {
                                validators: {
                                    notEmpty: {
                                        message: 'User Name required'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            password: {
                                validators: {
                                    notEmpty: {
                                        message: 'TPassword required'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <form action="login" method="post" id="login" > 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="userName">
                                            User Id
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="userName" id="userName" class="form-control lgn">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="Password">
                                            Password
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control lgn">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success lgn" >Login</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
    </body>
```

How to resolve this.

fiddle demo jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/3bthv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyqJH/)

The problem was that your js code contained in the fiddle contained syntax errors. The console should be the first thing you check when your javascript isn't working as expected. I commented in the code below what changes I made to get the fiddle to work. (It looks like the code in your question is fine though)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            userName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            } /* <-- removed unneeded comma */
        } /* <-- added closing brace */
    });
});
```